# Difference between 'if -e' and 'if -f'

Tags: bash, if-statement

There are two switches for the `if` condition which check for a file: `-e` and `-f`.

What is the difference between those two?

Comment: @jww It's a question about the if block in bash scripting - it might not be a programming language, but I sure wouldn't call it off topic.

Comment: Fair enough. You had it tagged as such; so you moved it towards programming and away from "how do I use this command". Retracted.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

See: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

I believe those aren't "if switches", rather "test switches" (because you have to use them inside [] brackets.

But the difference is:

`[ -e FILE ]` True if FILE exists.

This will return **true** for both `/etc/hosts` and `/dev/null` and for directories.

`[ -f FILE ]` True if FILE exists and is a regular file.
This will return **true** for `/etc/hosts` and **false** for `/dev/null` (because it is not a regular file), and **false** for `/dev` since it is a directory.

Comment: Directories are probably the most common things you'll encounter in the file system that aren't regular files.

Comment: Just my two cents, -e will output true with symlinks, that might come in handy when you want to validate that a file exists whether it's a directory, a symlink, or a regular file.

Answer (score 56):

```
$ man bash

       -e file
              True if file exists.
       -f file
              True if file exists and is a regular file.
```

A regular file is something that isn't a directory, symlink, socket, device, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Guess this means that for -f to become true, you have to reference to a file which isn't a link or something like that?

Comment: Yes. They typically have a `-` in the first character of ls -l output.

Comment: @Garrett Same for CentOS 6.9.

Comment: The reason why test command with `-f` returns true for symbolic link is answered by nos at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380068/what-is-the-regular-file-on-centos-and-ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

The if statement actually uses the program 'test' for the tests. You could write if statements two ways:

```
if [ -e filename ];
```

or

```
if test -e filename;
```

If you know this, you can easily check the man page for 'test' to find out the meanings of the different tests:

```
man test
```

Answer (score 6):

`-e` checks for *any* type of filesystem object; `-f` *only* checks for a regular file.