# What is "the regular file" on CentOS and Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, file-type

My environment is:

- CentOS 6.9
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

The GNU coreutils 8.4 has the test command to check the file using `-f` option.

`man test` shows

> ```
>   -f FILE
>          FILE exists and is a regular file
> ```

The definition of the "regular file" is ambiguous for me.

On the terminal, I did

```
$ touch afile
$ ln -fs afile LN-FILE
```

Then, I executed the following script (check_file_exist_180320_exec)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -e LN-file ]
then
    echo "file exists [-e]"
fi

if [ -f LN-file ]
then
    echo "file exists [-f]"
fi
```

For CentOS and Ubuntu, both show -e and -f for symbolic linked file (LN-FILE).

However, ls -l returns `l:symbolik link` (not `-:regular file`) identifiers for the LN-FILE file.
( see. https://linuxconfig.org/identifying-file-types-in-linux)

On the other hand, I found following, 
[Difference between if -e and if -f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204562/difference-between-if-e-and-if-f)

> A regular file is something that isn't a directory / symlink / socket / device, etc.
>
> answered Apr 18 '12 at 7:10
>
> jman

What is the reference I should check for the "regular file" (for CentOS and Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the documentation further down in `man test`

> Except for -h and -L, all FILE-related tests dereference symbolic
>   links.

Basically when you do `-f LN-file` , and LN-file is a symbolic link, the `-f` test will follow that symlink, and give you the result of what the symlink points to.

If you want to check if a file is a symlink or a regular file, you need to do e.g.

```
if [ -h LN-file ]
then
    echo "file is a symlink [-h]"
elif [ -f LN-file ]
then
    echo "file is a regular file [-f]"
fi
```

Comment: I see. The "-f" option checks the linked file, not the symbolic link and we should use it with care as your script (after -h check).

Comment: Almost every file interaction will cause a symlink to be dereferenced. And commonly one performs a `[ -f ]` test because some other program will interact with that file - that other program will see what the symlink points to, not that it's a symlink. So in most cases `[ -f ]` does what you want, and it's the special cases you need to care if the file is a symlink.

Comment: To tell the truth, I do not come up with the case I should distinguish the regular file (non-symbolic link) and the symbolic link. So, as you told, in most cases `[ -f ]` may do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

A regular file is a file that isn't a binary file neither a symbolic link.
It use to be associated to a plain text file.

Comment: `stat video.mkv` shows that this is regular file.