# What is the meaning of -n, -z, -x, -L, -d, etc... in Shell Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I often find on files `.sh` Shell Script in conditionals sintaxis like these:

```
if [ -n "condition" ]; then ...
if [ -z "condition "]; then ...
if [ -x "condition" ]; then ...
if [ -L "condition" ]; then ...
if [ -d "condition" ]; then ...
```

Those  `-n, -z, -x, -L, -d` are functions or how is it name and what is it purpose?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: or `man --pager='less -p"^CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS"' bash`

Comment: They're normal command line arguments for the `[` program. See [`man [`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

Comment: **1.** Since you make use of the `test` command (synonym to `[ ... ]`). Have a look at `man test`. **2.** be aware that there is a difference between `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` (See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204562, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869072

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IMHO best way is you could simply do `man test` for all these details. It is very well explained there. As follows is the text from man page. For BASH conditional expressions look for link https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html too once.

> ```
>    -b FILE
>           FILE exists and is block special
>
>    -c FILE
>           FILE exists and is character special
>
>    -d FILE
>           FILE exists and is a directory
>
>    -e FILE
>           FILE exists
>
>    -f FILE
>           FILE exists and is a regular file
>
>    -g FILE
>           FILE exists and is set-group-ID
>
>    -G FILE
>           FILE exists and is owned by the effective group ID
>
>    -h FILE
>           FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -L)
>
>    -k FILE
>           FILE exists and has its sticky bit set
>
>    -L FILE
>           FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -h)
>
>    -O FILE
>           FILE exists and is owned by the effective user ID
>
>    -p FILE
>           FILE exists and is a named pipe
>
>    -r FILE
>           FILE exists and read permission is granted
>
>    -s FILE
>           FILE exists and has a size greater than zero
>
>    -S FILE
>           FILE exists and is a socket
>
>    -t FD  file descriptor FD is opened on a terminal
>
>    -u FILE
>           FILE exists and its set-user-ID bit is set
>
>    -w FILE
>           FILE exists and write permission is granted
>
>    -x FILE
>           FILE exists and execute (or search) permission is granted
> ```

For expressions in `man test` it is given:

> ```
>    ( EXPRESSION )
>           EXPRESSION is true
>
>    ! EXPRESSION
>           EXPRESSION is false
>
>    EXPRESSION1 -a EXPRESSION2
>           both EXPRESSION1 and EXPRESSION2 are true
>
>    EXPRESSION1 -o EXPRESSION2
>           either EXPRESSION1 or EXPRESSION2 is true
>
>    -n STRING
>           the length of STRING is nonzero
>
>    STRING equivalent to -n STRING
>
>    -z STRING
>           the length of STRING is zero
>
>    STRING1 = STRING2
>           the strings are equal
>
>    STRING1 != STRING2
>           the strings are not equal
>
>    INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
>           INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2
>
>    INTEGER1 -ge INTEGER2
>           INTEGER1 is greater than or equal to INTEGER2
> ```

***For conditional expressions info go for `man bash` it gives info as follows too.***

> CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS
>          Conditional  expressions  are used by the [[ compound command and the test and [ builtin commands to test file attributes and
>   perform string and
>          arithmetic comparisons.  Expressions are formed from the following unary or binary primaries.  If any file argument to one of
>   the  primaries  is
>          of  the  form  /dev/fd/n, then file descriptor n is checked.  If the file argument to one of the primaries is one of /dev/stdin,
>   /dev/stdout, or
>          /dev/stderr, file descriptor 0, 1, or 2, respectively, is checked.
>
> ```
>    Unless otherwise specified, primaries that operate on files follow symbolic links and operate on the target of the link, rather
> ```
>
> than  the  link
>          itself.
>
> ```
>    When used with [[, The < and > operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.
> ```

Comment: `man test`. Man, I didn't know it's part of the built test command.